# Trouble rotating image on HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, image-rotation

I have the following code which is part of a larger script that allows a user put a photo on the Canvas, crop it, and then rotate it if it is not right side up.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    $('#rotateL').on( "click", {dir: -1}, rotate );
    $('#rotateR').on( "click", {dir: 1}, rotate );
    ....lots more code
}

function rotate(event) {
    var dir = event.data.dir;
    var canvasCopy = document.createElement("canvas");
    var copyContext = canvasCopy.getContext("2d");
    canvasCopy.width = clip.width;
    canvasCopy.height = clip.height;

    if (dir > 0) {
        copyContext.translate(clip.width, 0);
    } else {
        copyContext.translate(0, clip.height);
    }
    copyContext.rotate(Math.PI / (2 * dir));
    copyContext.drawImage(clip, 0, 0);
    clip.src = canvasCopy.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(clip, clip.x1, clip.y1);
}
```

The problem is this. When you click on one of the rotate buttons, on the first click, it does nothing and then works correctly on all subsequent clicks. If you then click the other rotate button to rotate in the opposite direction, it rotates the wrong direction on the first click and then works correctly on all subsequent clicks. I'm having trouble seeing the problem. Can anybody help me out with this?

Comment: I think the new image source did not have time to properly load before you requested it to be drawn. It seems you have two canvases, one to rotate the image on and then copy that look onto your viewing-canvas. As a test, try putting both canvases next to each other and compare them. The "canvas" should show the correctly rotated image and "Canvas" should stay 1 rotation-step behind. Why don't you let the image rotate in your main canvas?

Comment: I started off trying to rotate the image on the main canvas, but the clip was on a larger canvas and I was having trouble getting it to spin on its axis. I got frustrated and knew that I could easily fix the problem by using another, smaller, canvas. But then I ran into this problem. I haven't tried your suggestion yet, but if the image didn't have time to load properly, wouldn't the image be incomplete? My images are fine. They just don't rotate as expected on the first click.

Comment: Each time that you perform something like this: `image.src = "blabla"`, where you give your image variable a new source, it takes some time to load it and might not immediately be available to be drawn (at least from my own experience). Just to try it, move your line of code that draw the image to a separate function and call it with a delay: `setTimeout(drawFunction,2000)` just to see if that is in fact the problem.

Comment: I meant to write this comment a long time ago, but only just got around to it. It turns out that Niddro was right. I added a 100 m/sec delay anytime the script had to reload the image source and that fixed the problem. In my testing I found out that this turns out to be a problem unique (I only tested IE, Chrome and Firefox) to Firefox. The code ran as expected on the other browsers without the delay which caused me to be more confused about the problem and, at first, I thought it was just a bug in Firefox. I hope this comment helps anyone else who is having this problem.